# MonoDroid GetSpans last parameter

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android, spannable

I'm trying to use ISpannable in a Monodroid project but am having problems with GetSpans.  What I'm ultimately after is a Rich Text editor such as at:

https://code.google.com/p/android-richtexteditor/source/browse/?r=4#svn/trunk/src/net/sgoliver

However, the Xamarin documentation for [GetSpans](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aAndroid.Text.ISpanned.GetSpans%28System.Int32,System.Int32,Java.Lang.Class%29) isn't particularly helpful.  The line I'm trying to convert from Java to C# is:

```
StyleSpan[] ss = s.getSpans(styleStart, position, StyleSpan.class);
```

However, I don't know what to pass for the last parameter as writing StyleSpan.class in C# gives a compile error of "} expected".  What can I pass in to the last parameter to get all spans, or all spans of a particular type?

Comment: GetSpans returns an array of Java.Lang.Object's. How did you convert back to an array of StyleSpans?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The C# equivalent should be `Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(StyleSpan))`.