# How to remove underline from the hyperlink textview in xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

### Explanation

I have used textview inside that there is a link, when i click on that it goes to the webpage. To create a link i used anchor tag of html.

This is the xml file where i created the link

```
<TextView
        android:text="@string/Home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textColorLink="#b3b3b3"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/Terms" />
```

This is the string.xml file where i created the link

```
<string name="Home"><a href="https://www.google.co.in/ " style="color:rgb(179, 179, 179);text-decoration:none">Home</a>
```

I tried using the css style text-decoration:none which doesn't work.

Also i tried from this link  [Remove underline from links in TextView - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096851/remove-underline-from-links-in-textview-android)
In that spannable doesn't work in c#

### Question

How can i remove the underline from the hyperlink?

[image: This is the image showing the hyperlink with underline]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to remove underline from the hyperlink textview in xamarin android

The link you posted above is correct. I simplify `Reuben Scratton`'s code and was able to remove the underline.

`URLSpanNoUnderline` class :

```
public class URLSpanNoUnderline : URLSpan
{
    public URLSpanNoUnderline(String url) : base(url)
    {
    }

    public override void UpdateDrawState(TextPaint ds)
    {
        base.UpdateDrawState(ds);
        ds.UnderlineText = false;
    }
}
```

Remove the underline from the hyperlink `TextView` :

```
private void stripUnderlines(TextView textView)
{
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(textView.Text);
    s.SetSpan(new URLSpanNoUnderline(textView.Text), 0, s.Length(), SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);
    textView.SetText(s, TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
}
```

## Update :

Here is a workaround to solve the click issue:

You could use `ClickableSpan` instead of `URLSpan` to implement the same feature. You could refer to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48227808/xamarin-unable-to-retrieve-urlspans-from-a-textview-with-links), then modify your code like this :

```
textview.MovementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.Instance;
textview.Text = GetString(Resource.String.Home);

SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(textview.Text);
ss.SetSpan(new MyClickableSpan(this), 0, ss.Length(), SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);
textview.SetText(ss, TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
```

Here is the `MyClickableSpan` code :

```
class MyClickableSpan : ClickableSpan
{
    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    public MyClickableSpan(MainActivity mainActivity)
    {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

    public override void OnClick(View widget)
    {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Uri.Parse("https://www.google.co.in/"));
        mainActivity.StartActivity(browserIntent);
    }

    public override void UpdateDrawState(TextPaint ds)
    {
        base.UpdateDrawState(ds);
        ds.Color = Color.Red;
        ds.UnderlineText = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Anish, it did remove the underline, but can you open the hyperlink when you chick the `TextView`?

Comment: I was just checking that now. It gives android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent error. Any idea about it?@York Shen

Comment: @Anish, I have updated my answer, I spend a whole day to find the workaround, hope this can help you. : )

Comment: This doesn't really work, it creates one url span for the entire string rather than maintaining the position of the individual url spans within the text.

Answer (score 0):

just update the method as below

the order should be : setting text color, calling base mehtod , setting underline mode

```
   public override void UpdateDrawState(TextPaint ds)
   {
        ds.LinkColor = Android.Graphics.Color.Blue.ToArgb();
        base.UpdateDrawState(ds);
        ds.UnderlineText = false;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

York's answer won't work if you have a mix of text and urls in your TextView content, it sets the entire first line of text in your textview into a UrlSpan. Instead, to preserve where the urls should actually go, you can do the following:

```
public static void StripUnderlinesFromLinks (this TextView textView) {
            var spannable = new SpannableStringBuilder (textView.TextFormatted);
            var spans = spannable.GetSpans (0, spannable.Length (), Java.Lang.Class.FromType (typeof (URLSpan)));
            foreach (URLSpan span in spans) {
                var start = spannable.GetSpanStart (span);
                var end = spannable.GetSpanEnd (span);
                spannable.RemoveSpan(span);
                var newSpan = new URLSpanNoUnderline (span.URL);
                spannable.SetSpan(newSpan, start, end, 0);
            }
            textView.TextFormatted = spannable;
        }

class URLSpanNoUnderline : URLSpan {
        public URLSpanNoUnderline (string url) : base (url) {
        }

        public override void UpdateDrawState (TextPaint ds) {
            base.UpdateDrawState (ds);
            ds.UnderlineText = false;
        }
    }
```